# c++ recursive call parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, recursion

I was browsing the OpenCV source code when I got this function in /core/src/convert.cpp:

```
void merge(const cv::vector<cv::Mat>& mv, cv::Mat _dst)
{
    merge(&mv[0] ,3, _dst);
}
```

How could the Original function with only 2 parameters:

> merge(const cv::vector& mv, cv::Mat _dst)

and the recursive call with 3 parameters

> merge(const cv::Mat*,**int**, cv::Mat&)

Comment: There might be another overloaded version of `merge`. Just keep looking.

Comment: No their is not :D I just Opened a new project and copy this function and call it from the main and It is working !!

Comment: Well that can't be. Remember you have some includes :). New project is not an empty project.

Comment: Oh yes :D I think you are right I am including some libraries may be the overloading in them.

Comment: What you are saying is not possible. It is simply not possible to write a function call such as merge(&mv[0] ,3, _dst); and that it works "just by magic".

Comment: If you have a good IDE you can easily find where it is defined. VS right click and go to definition. OR if linux, debug, break and step in to the function.

Comment: I am using Qt creator and when I just push F@ to go to the definition it point to the first merge function with 2 parameters !!

Comment: Maybe QT refactoring doesn't recognize overloading. Try debugging. Put a break point there and then **step into** the function.

Comment: for sure I did but I got that the merge function when stepping into :
const_reference
      operator[](size_type __n) const
      { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }

Comment: this is not an overloading function for merge isn't it ??

Comment: Ok I found the overloaded function :D thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not a recursive call. The call

```
merge(&mv[0] ,3, _dst);
```

is not calling

```
void merge(const cv::vector<cv::Mat>& mv, cv::Mat _dst)
```

That much is clear since the parameter count does not match.

The explanation is that `merge` is overloaded. There is another version with three parameters.  That three parameter version is declared in one of the header files that you included.

Answer (score 1):

`merge(&mv[0] ,3, _dst);` is not a call to `void merge(const cv::vector<cv::Mat>& mv, cv::Mat _dst)`.

There is must be somewhere an overloaded function, i.e. a function with the same name, but a different signature. One such as `void merge(const cv::vector<cv::Mat>& mv, int something, cv::Mat _dst)`.